# How to receive image file path shared from gallery to react native app

Tags: android, react-native

My goal is to open an Image Upload screen of my react native app and fetch that shared image file path (like as `file://`). I want to receive the image file path shared from the gallery to react native app. I am beginner to this and I have searched on google and stack Overflow and found this to add in MainActivity.java file, although I am receiving the image as `content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/38` but I don't know how to convert this filePath to file path like `file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.newProject/files/Pictures/ff345380-4bbd-4153-8a8b-c6f98ae62627.jpg`.
MainActivity.java file

```
@Override
protected ReactActivityDelegate createReactActivityDelegate() {
    return new ReactActivityDelegate(this, getMainComponentName()) {
       
        @Override
        protected Bundle getLaunchOptions() {

            Intent intent = MainActivity.this.getIntent();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            Uri imageUri = intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
            
            if (imageUri != null) {
                bundle.putString("image", imageUri.toString());
            }else{
                bundle.putString("image", "");
            }
            
            return bundle;
        }

    };
}
```

Also, I am only receiving the image path when the app is closed, when it is already open in the background, it is not receiving the image file path.
I am searching for the code in React native or by using the native method. If I got a native solution then I will pass that filePath(converted) as an initial prop with the bundle.

Comment: This question also points to the same problem [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58333729/how-to-share-images-from-android-gallery-to-react-native-app)

Comment: please clarify what you are trying to get to ? the code you posted is java android after it has been `ejected`, `converted`, `etc..`. do you just want some react-native code or do you want to add the upload screen natively "meaning in java and android studio or in react-native?"

Comment: Thanks, @forthelulx Upload screen is a react-native js file, I want a code in native so that I can convert this absolute path to file path or third party module in react native, for this conversion